# How is the code button in the post editor implemented?

Tags: support, editor

On Stack Overflow, how is the "enter the code" button implemented?

Comment: Where is the *enter the code* button? You mean the button with the zeros and ones?

Comment: yeah . the buttons with 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

See the function `command.doCode` in [wmd.js](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/source/browse/wmd.js) (in the current version, it starts at line 2106). It should be pretty much self-explaining.